# Не работают уведомления NotificationCompat

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Добрый день, друзья. Я новичок в программировании и в данный момент клепаю простое приложение-напоминалку.
Суть проблемы: в заданное время напоминания просто не срабатывают. Ни ошибки, ничего. Отладочное сообщение в теле метода создания уведомления так же не появляется, т.е. как я понимаю процесс в этот блок даже не доходит. Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Код деятельности, которая создает уведомление

```
public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

    public ReminderService() {
        super("ReminderService");
    }


    @Override
    void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
        Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RemindersEdit.class);

        notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);


        Notification notification = builder
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.note_icon)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message))
            .build();
        Log.d ("Note","Note has to be done" );

        int id = (int) ((long) rowId);
        mgr.notify(id, notification);
    }
}
```

Она наследует этот класс (отвечает за блокировки отключения процессора)

```
public abstract class WakeReminderIntentService extends IntentService { 
    abstract void doReminderWork(Intent intent);

    public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC = "com.dummies.android.taskreminder.Static";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;

    public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
        getLock(context).acquire();
    }

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic==null) {
            PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        return(lockStatic);
    }
    public WakeReminderIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            doReminderWork(intent);
        } finally {
            getLock(this).release();
        }
    }
}
```

И, наверное, еще класс установки напоминания стоит показать

```
public class ReminderManager{

    private Context mContext;
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    public ReminderManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {
        Log.d("SetReminder", "Started");
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long) taskId);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Код OnAlarmReciever, в который кидается намерение из ReminderManager.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long rowid =
            intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);


    WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

    Intent i = new Intent(context,ReminderService.class);

    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowid);
    context.startService(i);
    Log.d ("OnAlarmReciever", "onRecieveDone");
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код класса `OnAlarmReceiver`, в который кидается Intent из `RemindManager`

Comment: Спасибо, добавил!